# How to keep track of users in React?

Tags: java, reactjs, session, cookies, jax-rs

How can I keep track of a user's session after page reload?

I have a web application consisting of a front end built with React, and a back end built with JAX-RS. Both communicate over RESTful and JSON. When the user loads the app, the front end asks the back end for a session which is a unique alphanumeric number to identify every user and every of his actions on the app. But, if the user hits the browser's refresh button, the app is reloaded and pulls a new session number. Out of the view of the backend this is now a new user.

But I would like to keep track of the user. My current approach is to put a cookie in the user's browser aimed for identification. Is that the right approach? Or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting cookies or saving in localstorage or sessionstorage in browser is good approach, you can go forward with it:

For storing data :

```
localStorage.setItem("session_id", <value>)
sessionStorage.setItem("session_id", <value>)
```

For retrieving data :

```
localStorage.getItem("session_id")
sessionStorage.getItem("session_id")
```

Comment: What library do you use for `localStorage` and for `sessionStorage`?

Comment: you don't, it's supported, just do these lines and it will work. @Socrates

Comment: Have a read at localStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and sessionStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), it is supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Set cookie with user token, and when user refresh, first check for the cookie , if it is there continue, else ask API to send new.
Use react-cookies library.

import cookie from 'react-cookies'

These are the functions available.

To set a cookie use

```
cookie.save(key, value)
```

To fetch cookie in app use

```
cookie.load(key)
```

And to remove it when session ends, you can use

```
cookie.remove(key)
```